# How to configure Userid/Password on a client side for a WCF service in config file and not in code

Tags: java, wcf, binding, wsdl

Requirement is to call a Java Web Service. There is a WSDL provided. Call is successful in unsecured fashion. Now the service call needs to be authenticated. Service call will be successful only via a paricular windows userid/password. Since everything in our application is config based, we don't want to hard-code anything in code. Appreciate if someone can show how to do so ?

I have this config by the way....

```
  <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="MyBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" 
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>


  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the username/password anywhere in the WCF-specific configuration. You can, however, set the username/password pair as application settings, retrieve them from the code, and set them in the WCF client.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" value="My user name" />
    <add key="Password" value="Your secret password" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and in the code:

```
var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

Comment: I kind of already figured out from other posts here, but still wanted to try my luck. Thank you so much carlos.